# How much RAM and CPU do various IRC Daemons take up?

Tags: daemon, irc

I'm looking to install an IRC Daemon, as well as services (if they are not included in the IRC daemon) onto a virtual server with a variable amount of memory allocation, and I was wondering about how much RAM and CPU the daemon takes up on average, as well as what kind of behavior it demonstrates (CPU spikes, RAM spikes, things like that).

I'm leaning towards UnrealIRCD for the most part, but if there are daemons that are designed to be "light", I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I used to run [ircu](http://coder-com.undernet.org/) on a pentium 100 with 48MB of memory some years ago. It was running well with thousands of users.
With a modern server you probably don't have to care too much for CPU/RAM

Comment: That's good to know, I'll look into that IRCd.

Answer (score 1):

I ran UnrealIRCd on a Pentium 133 with 32MB RAM years ago ,but would recommend against UnrealIRCd as it's really just poorly put together and is not well-maintained any more.

My IRCd of choice these days is [charybdis](http://www.stack.nl/~jilles/irc/#charybdis), which on my installation is currently consuming about 5 MB of RAM. One nice thing about charybdis is that it is highly modular, so you can literally not load any piece of functionality you don't use if you are really that pressed for memory.

The best services package around is atheme, which I can't link to because of spam prevention, but you should have no trouble Googling it.